# Apache is not starting in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I installed tomcat and mySQL. I was trying to start Apache and MySQL in XAMPP. My Apache is not starting.I changed the port numbers in the config file of XAMPP.no result.This is my error message now.

```
8:23:07 AM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
  8:23:07 AM  [main]    Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 7.4.2
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th 2019 ]
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  All prerequisites found
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  Initializing Modules
    8:23:07 AM  [mysql]     XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3307
    8:23:07 AM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected!
    8:23:07 AM  [Tomcat]    Port 8080 in use by "C:\ oraclexe \app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server   \BIN\tnslsnr.exe"!
    8:23:07 AM  [Tomcat]    Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
    8:23:07 AM  [Tomcat]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
    8:23:07 AM  [Tomcat]    or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
    8:23:07 AM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
    8:24:20 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
    8:24:20 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
    8:24:21 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I changed the port to 8086.Still not working.
Please help me

Comment: I changed port and servername in httpd.conf and changed listen and virtualHost_default in httpd-ssl.conf. It worked!!.Thanks

Comment: if you have found the solution, try giving the solution and path of the file so the future user can refer your question directly.